# Give style to a border but not text in css

Tags: css, border

is there any way to edit the border in css but not the contents within the border? such as ".border" or something similar?
For example: 
I want to give a border a neon outline, but I don't want to edit the contents within the border. 
thanks

Comment: In CSS there is actually a `border` property. Have you checked it out?

Comment: Can you show any examples of what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple to edit the border without affecting the content using the `border` property as already stated in the comments. Here are a few simple examples of a text with a border around it. You can also add a box shadow for a glowing neon effect, or use multiple borders to make it glow more.

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: white;
  width:100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.border1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px red;
  color: white;
  width:100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.border2 {
  border: 1px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px red;
  color: white;
  width:100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
body {
background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
Basic Border 
</div>
<hr>
<div class="border1">
Neon 
</div>
<hr>
<div class="border1">
<div class="border2">
Even more neon
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The border property in CSS can be really powerful, especially if you get right up in there.

Take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border.

I particularly like playing around with `border-top-left-radius`/`border-bottom-right-radius` etc to avoid relying on buttons.

For example:

```css
.fakeNeonBtn {
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #48ff00;
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    /*border-radius: 10px; If all border radius' are the same just use this*/
    /* otherwise see below*/
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.fakeNeonBtn:hover {
    border: 2px solid black;
    background: rgba(210, 255, 82, 1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(210, 255, 82, 1) 0%, rgba(179, 244, 74, 1) 47%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(210, 255, 82, 1)), color-stop(47%, rgba(179, 244, 74, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(210, 255, 82, 1) 0%, rgba(179, 244, 74, 1) 47%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(210, 255, 82, 1) 0%, rgba(179, 244, 74, 1) 47%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(210, 255, 82, 1) 0%, rgba(179, 244, 74, 1) 47%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(210, 255, 82, 1) 0%, rgba(179, 244, 74, 1) 47%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 1) 100%);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d2ff52', endColorstr='#91e842', GradientType=1);
}
```

```html
<p class="fakeNeonBtn">Fake Button</p>
```